# Background-position not working when classname changed in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have an element which I am adding a class to.

the style is:

```
.bg{ background: url(/images/background.png) no-repeat top center #000; }
```

When I add the class with javascript the background image show up, and the color show up, but the positioning does not.

This works fine in everything except IE

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the CSS `background:` shorthand properly - you're missing the `background-repeat` part. It should be something like this:

```
.bg {
    background: #000000 url(/images/background.png) no-repeat scroll center top;
}          /*   ^       ^                           ^           ^     ^
                color   image                       repeat attachment position */
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: Actually, I have no-repeat in there.  My mistake I omitted that.  The issue is not the CSS.  It looks fine, if the class is there when the page loads.  However if the class is added with javascript.  Background position is not respected. (IN IE)

Comment: I always do `background:#bgcolor url(filename) no-repeat 0 0;` and that seems to work pretty well.

Comment: -1. There is no "middle" value, and you got the vertical and horisontal values swapped. You might want to check out the page that you linked to... ;)

Comment: @Guffa: yeah, I didn't try it out - just copied the CSS from the OP... poorly. Must stop posting on SO while cooking.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a vertical value (top), and one that doesn't exist (middle).

The vertical values are `top`, `center` and `bottom`, while the horisontal are `left`, `center` and `right`.

When using both, the first is the horisontal and the second is the vertical, so you got them backwards.

Use:

```
.bg{ background: #000 url(/images/background.png) no-repeat center top; }
```